# Remove one of the ng-repeat selected item onItemSelect event in angularjs dropdown multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) on my form. What is the fastest way to remove the `selectedItem` on the `onItemSelect` event if it meets a condition?

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in mainCtrl.lineDetails">
    <td>
        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="true" options="mainCtrl.Options" 
             selected-model="detail.SelectedOptions"
             extra-settings="{
               searchField: 'name',
               enableSearch: true,
               displayProp: 'name',
               scrollableHeight: '300px',
               scrollable: true,
               keyboardControls: true,
               idProperty: 'id',
               buttonClasses: 'form-control drpdwn-btn',
               styleActive: true,
               selectionLimit:detail.SelectedLimit}"
             events="{ onItemSelect: mainCtrl.checkSelected,
                       onSelectAll: mainCtrl.checkSelectedAll }">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Currently I'm just going through the whole `mainCtrl.lineDetails` then `detail.SelectedOptions` and then checking each item for the same id and then checking if it meets my condition then removing in the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you can is track the Index on the ng-repeat than, on Item Select pass the Index and splice the element from mainCtrl.lineDetails array.

Example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(index, detail) in mainCtrl.lineDetails">
    <td>
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="true" options="mainCtrl.Options" 
         selected-model="detail.SelectedOptions"
         extra-settings="{
           searchField: 'name',
           enableSearch: true,
           displayProp: 'name',
           scrollableHeight: '300px',
           scrollable: true,
           keyboardControls: true,
           idProperty: 'id',
           buttonClasses: 'form-control drpdwn-btn',
           styleActive: true,
           selectionLimit:detail.SelectedLimit}"
         events="{ onItemSelect: removeLineDetailItem,
                   onSelectAll: mainCtrl.checkSelectedAll }">
    </div>
</td>


// Make a function on your ctrl which will be fired onItemSelect event
$scope.removeLineDetailItem(item) {
   const index = $scope.lineDetails.findIndex(val => val == item);
   $scope.lineDetails.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Comment: `removeLineDetailItem(index)` gets called repeatedly even when user does not select the item.

Comment: Check if you can get the Item Index on the event of onItemSelect, otherwise if you cant, try the above edited snippet.